# Sorting an array of arrays of integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a variable dimensions, which contains the maximum size of each element of an array, e.g.:

```
const dimensions = [10, 6, 4]
```

I also have an array of arrays containing as many integers as the size of the `dimensions` array, e.g.:

```
let boxes = [
    [1, 2, 1],
    [10, 2, 4],
    [4, 1, 1],
    [10, 2, 3]
]
```

For every array in `boxes`, no element will be higher than its counterpart in `dimensions`.

I want to find a way to **sort** these arrays, so that the sorted array `boxes` would be:

```
[
    [1, 2, 1],
    [4, 1, 1],
    [10, 2, 3],
    [10, 2, 4]
]
```

As you see, it's not just about sorting by the array's first element. It's sorting by first element, and if they're equal, the second, etc.

For each array of arrays, I have a related `dimensions` variable. But dimensions can be anything (also any *length*!) (and consequently, the arrays will have the same length of course).

I'm doing this in Javascript, but pseudocode is welcome too.

PS - This is not part of an assignment, I tried to abstract away most of the unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the values using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to compare the values in each array being sorted, only updating the comparison result if it is currently `0` (i.e. the values up to now have been equal):

```js
let boxes = [
  [1, 2, 1],
  [10, 2, 4],
  [4, 1, 1],
  [10, 2, 3]
]

boxes.sort((a, b) => a.reduce((c, v, i) => c ? c : v - b[i], 0));

console.log(boxes);
```